# EWR Gate B26 doesn't exist

Tags: ewr

Why does UA list my arrival gate at B26 in Newark but looking at a map it doesn't exist on any of them??  Trying to calculate connection time needed.

Comment: @zaph: How do you get "A23" in particular?

Comment: oops, correction: They probably mean A26. Airline personnel are not really good at details customers need.

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing this listing?  United website (which section)? United app (which section)?  Somewhere else?

Comment: Please add some more details to make this question answerable. Where does it say B26? Can you screenshot/scan whatever piece of information you have that says this? If you do please edit sensitive data such as names, etc.

Comment: Go to [EWR Airport Maps](https://www.newarkairport.com/at-airport/airport-maps) and select the terminal A, B or C. Basically gates 10-38 are in Terminal A, 40-68 are in terminal B, 70-130 are in Terminal C. So, if the **number** is really 26 the **gate** most likely is A26. (could be worse, there are three platform 1 in the Bologna train station ad they care not adjacent to each other.)